# "Call" post information from "post_id"

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So I have custom posts by various users.

Each post has following meta keys:

`post_width`, `post_height` along with usual data such as `title`, `description` etc as shown below:

```
$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
$custom_field_1 = $_POST['custom_1'];
$custom_field_2 = $_POST['custom_2']; 

$post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $description,
    'post_category' => $_POST['cat'], 
    'tags_input'    => $tags,                                   
    'post_status'   => 'publish',           
    'post_type' => $_POST['post_type']  
    );                              
$pid = wp_insert_post($post);
add_post_meta($pid, 'post_width', $custom_field_1, true);
add_post_meta($pid, 'post_height', $custom_field_2, true);
```

Now when these posts are displayed in a loop, they each get `post_id` by `$id = get_the_ID();`

**Now the fun part**

Now, let say there are 5 posts displayed and each has unique `post_id` as shown below in the `data-post_id` in a button.

```
 <?php echo '<button type="button" class="contact_button" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ;?>
    Open the contact form
 <?php echo '</button>';?>
```

When the button is clicked, then a below contact form will be shown :

```
 <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
      <p><label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
      <p><label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
      <p><label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
      <p><label for="message_human">Human Verification: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
         <p><input type="submit"></p>
  </form>
```

As you can see, the contact form is nothing fancy.

**Here is what I am trying to achieve**

Since there are 5 posts, I want to make it very specific to each post when the contact form is sent.

Here is what I mean.

Let say there are 5 posts as shown below:

**Post # 1:**

- **Title:** What a day
- **Post Author:** Mike
- **Post author's Email:** mike@example.com
- **Post descript:** It is a sunny day
- **Width:** 14px
- **Height:** 15px
- **Contact Button**

**Post # 2:**

- **Title:** This is a post 2
- **Post Author:** Steve
- **Post author's Email:** steve@example.com
- **Post descript:** It is Sunday
- **Width:** 1222px
- **Height:** 1233px
- **Contact Button**

etc.

Now, each post has `contact button` and when the button is clicked and contact form is shown, I want to automatically have these `post meta` to be filled in (of course hidden from view). So that when the form is submitted, it will have post information and be able to tell which post the viewer contacted from.

I hope I am making sense.

**So, here is my question.**

How do I `call` or `save` post meta (such as title, description, custom meta, etc) based on the `post_id` of each post? (since each button will have unique `post_id`, that will be a good starting point to `call` the rest of the data)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update 1:**

So, I have the contact form in a `contact.php` which is called via ajax.

The reason why I am using the ajax to call the contact form is to save the bandwidth. Here is a scenario. Let say there are 50 posts on a single page. Then if the `contact form` is generated for all the posts, then that will severely increase the total page size.

In order to avoid it, I am implementing ajax to call the contact form only when the button is clicked.

**So, here is a question.**

How do I "pass" the `post_id` to another php file? (contact_form.php) so that the contact form will be unique?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
 get_post_meta()
```

Something similar to this:

```
 $custom-meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom-meta', true)
```

You could find more info here.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

As for the title you could just do this

```
 $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
 echo $post_title
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

You could then add hidden fields to your form with that data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I made an update on the post. So in a summary, I am using ajax to call the  "contact form" to save the bandwidth. Now, would you happen to know how to pass the post id and its meta keys to another "file" ?

Comment: Your forms actions should be the path to the file that processes the form. This is what I use when doing that inside a plugin. You need to make sure your ajax is set-up though.


<form action='<?php plugins_url(); ?>/your-plugins-name/file_name.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try